# HTTPS block domain

Tags: apache, https, dns

When having multiple domain names point to the same server. But you only have a certificate for one of these domains, is it possible to block the other domains in Apache. But only when HTTPS is used not when HTTP is used.

I tried using a NameVirtualHost setup for 443 port. But when the domain is not found Apache simply defaults to the first virtual host. I would like it to refuse the connection. In this way when connecting directly through HTTPS on one of the not supported domains the connection is refused rather then having the browser display warning screen because of a wrong identity.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible.
This is a chicken and egg problem - to verify an https connection the browser connects and tries to validate the certificate/common name and the given URL.  The first handshake / connection to port 443 has to be encrypted.

The only way to handle this problem would be to setup dedicated IPs for all domains - or for at least the domain using HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

It's far from ideal, but another option would be to use a non-standard for your HTTPS site and  not have the server listening on port 443.

Comment: Do you mean non-standard port? That wouldn't just be far from ideal, it would be unacceptable. Serving a perfectly valid website with a valid certificate from a non-standard port would just seem suspicious. That would break the idea of using SSL.

Comment: @Dave: SSL is used for encryption as well as proving who you are, and I was not sure what your use case is.  I use non-standard HTTPS ports for encrypting `shellinabox`, while still running a website on port 443, so it is still a valid answer, if not for yourself.

Comment: @paradriod: I do not see how setting up a vhost on a non-standard port changes the behavior of Apache using SSL or not. The first vhost will still popup if the requested domain is not explicitly bound to a vhost. Thus the user would still get certs errors even on a non-standard port. Please clarify how this answer solves the problem? Or is your intend just to obfuscate so users are unlikely to encounter the problem?

Comment: @Dave: The SSL cert details for the site on the non-standard port will not be seen by any user going to the HTTPS site on the standard port, or `https://<IP-ADDRESS>.  They will need to now the full URL, with port number.  While this may not be a solution which you can use, it is a way to avoid those details being known.